# Countdown Timer Won't Work

Tags: iphone, timer, nstimer, countdown

My countdown timer won't work. It started with '99' on the screen and it just stop there. It doesn't move at all.

In my header file.

```
@interface FirstTabController : UIViewController {
    NSTimer *myTimer; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

In my .m file

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countDown {
    int counterInt = 100;

    int newTime = counterInt - 1;
    lblCountdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
}
```

And I invalidate 'myTimer' in my dealloc. So, Can anybody tell me whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each time your timer method is called you set `counterInt` (back) to 100.

you could make that a static variable

change `int counterInt = 100;` into `static int counterInt = 100;`

and of course you have to save the decremented value in counterInt.

```
- (void)countDown {
    static int counterInt = 100;
    counterInt = counterInt - 1;
    lblCountdown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counterInt];
}
```

---

if you need the variable outside of this method you should make counterInt a instance variable of your class.

```
@interface FirstTabController : UIViewController {
    int counterInt;
}
```

and so on.